# How to make observable array in knockout js model and bind it to html via view js in magento2

Tags: magento2, knockout

I want to make one observable array in knockout js model and this array need updating on click event:

That is what I have tried:

**js/model/test.js**

```
var testArray = ko.observableArray();

test : function(){
testArrayy()[0]=true;
testArray()[1]=false;

}
```

Now in **js/view/test.js**

I have made a test variable: `test.test;` and bind it with **test.html**:

```
<div data-bind:"visible:test.[0]:>test0 div</div>
```

But it's not working.

Does anyone know how to observe array through model and bind it via view js

All other logic I already know. I have just written pseudo for a basic idea here.

**My main question is:**
How to bind observable array using key and value in Magento 2?

let me give me example what i want actually to do:

INDIA
GUJARAT(visible if click on india)
RAJKOT(visible if click on gujarat)
GONDAL(visible if click on gondal)
AMERICA

there are many options which we need to visible on click

it's just a simple example

Comment: Do you mean Vue.js?

Comment: no js/view in magento2

Comment: did you try something like: `<div data-bind="foreach observable_array">` and then within the `<div>` access the value of your array with this `<span data-bind="visible: shouldBeVisible">` assuming thats your array: `{shouldBeVisible: true}`

Comment: actually array not observed on click or may be i dont know proper debugging in KO

Comment: can you explain what you actually want to do?

Comment: i want to to set visibility  using ko array on click event

Comment: is it multidimensional array?

Comment: check in my question what i am upto for make functionality i have updated my question and wrote small example

Answer (score 4):

In your model file declare a variable like this.

```
define(['ko'], function(ko) {
    'use strict';
    var array1 = ko.observable([]);
    var array2 = ko.observable([]);
    return {
        array1: array1,
        array2: array2,
    };
});
```

and in `view/test.js` file

```
define(
        [
            'jquery',
            'ko',
            'uiComponent',
            'Vendor_Module/js/model/test'
        ],
        function($, ko, Component,mytest) {
           mytest.array1(['your multidiamation array here']);

});
```

Hope it will help you.

UPDATE:

https://inviqa.com/blog/using-knockout-js-magento-2

Comment: i want to set the array value with key and also it in model js not view

Comment: I think you can not set values directly in model without using view or action

Comment: then how can set template and bind value in template?

Comment: using view files not model. Model is only use to pass data between models or view or action. like registry you can say

Comment: @RakeshVarma Can you please tell how to set array value with specific key  965=>"your multidiamation array here"

Comment: @RutveeSojitra you can set something like this. [
    { key1: "value1" },
    { key2: "value2" },
]